# Print out Powershell Groupmembers

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am trying to write a Powershellscript, that read out all Members of the groups(Which are standing in the txt)into a column in my csv.
 But i have the Problem that the output in my csv is that just the last member of each group print out around 300x

```
Clear-Host
#$zusammen = Liste von allen Usern
#$namen = Liste von allen bereits vorgekommenden UserUnids
#$gruppen = Liste von allen bereits vorgekommenden Gruppennamen
$zusammen = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)


#Pfad zur txt/csv Datei wo die Gruppen enthalten sind
$path = "C:\gruppen.txt"
#Inhalt der Datei laden
$inpt = Get-Content $path
$la = 1
#Objekt für die Ausgabe wird definiert
foreach ($temp in $inpt)
    {
        if($la -eq 1)
        {
            $objAusgabe = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
            $objAusgabe | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name $temp -Value $temp
            $la = 2
        }
        else
        {
            $objAusgabe | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name $temp -Value $temp
        }
    }
    $mitte = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)

foreach ($temp in $inpt)
{
#$usr = Gruppenname
$usr = $temp

#Funktion zum Suchen der User
function Findusers($objparam)
{


    foreach($ent in $objparam)
    {

        #$objmitte = New-Object -TypeName PSObject | Select UNID
        $objuser1 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+$ent)
        #usrtype gibt durch den samaccounttype an ob es sich um einen user oder eine gruppe handelt
        #wenn es eine gruppe ist wird die if-schleife durchlaufen sonst die else schleife
        $usrtype = $objuser1.sAMAccountType
        if($usrtype -eq 268435456 -or $usrtype -eq 268435457)
        {
                    "`t`t" + $objuser1.name + " -- Gruppe "
                    $Gabe = [string]$objuser1.name
                    $mitte.Add($Gabe) |Out-Null 
        }
        else
        {
                    "`t`t"+$objuser1.cn.ToUpper()+" -- "+$objuser1.sn+","+$objuser1.givenname
                    $unidgroß = [string]$objuser1.cn
                    $gabe = $unidgroß.ToUpper()
                    $mitte.Add($gabe) |Out-Null
        }
    }
    $test = $mitte
    foreach($tempo in $test)
    {
        $objAusgabe.$temp = $tempo
        $zusammen.Add($objAusgabe)|Out-Null
    }
}

$str = $usr + ":-" 
$str
Echo "---------------------------------------------"
$objItem = @()
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=Group)(name=$usr))"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree" 
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll() 
foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
{  
    $objItem = $objResult.GetDirectoryEntry()
    $objmem = $objItem.member
    Findusers($objmem)
}
}
$zusammen | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File C:\test.csv -Encoding unicode
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't simply use [`Get-ADGroupMember`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617193.aspx) from the `ActiveDirectory` PowerShell module?

Comment: because then i have to install the modul on about 200 servers

Comment: Big deal. `dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-Powershell`

Comment: Won't you have to install this script on 200 servers as well? Wouldn't be about the same difficulty to install one as the other (or even easier) to install the ad module?